# How can I get a floating average over timestamps in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a table for a time-sheet like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    spent_on DATETIME,
    hours FLOAT
)
```

Assuming `spent_on` is the timestamp the value was logged, and `hours` is a floating point value representing the amount of hours spent on a task.

How can I get a floating average of hours over the past 7 days?

I've came up with the following but it won't work:

```
select spent_on, hours, avg(hours)
over RANGE BETWEEN spent_on - INTERVAL '7 days' AND CURRENT ROW from daily;
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ROW"
LINE 1: ... BETWEEN spent_on - INTERVAL '7 days' AND CURRENT ROW from d...
```

I've tried to understand the docs for window functions, but I have real trouble grasping the idea between partitions, windows and frames. And as a result, can't come up with a query.

Comment: Unfortunately Postgres currently does not support ranges based on intervals.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the `RANGE` syntax, so let me offer a solution with a sub query (If performance is not an issue with small tables ETC..) :

```
SELECT t.spent_on,t.hours,
      COALESCE( (SELECT AVG(s.hours) FROM foo
        WHERE t.spent_on > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '7 days'),0) float_avg
FROM foo t
```

Comment: I tried this. It kind of works, but I have problems with NULL values (some rows contain NULLS). Not sure how I could combine this with a `coalesce` call...